# How to transform a single "n" number to an array, which will contain n number of arrays and in each Array will be n elements with text

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, data-transform

I need to transform a single "n" number to an array, which will contain n number of arrays and each Array will contain n elements with text that will display the position of particular element. For example for number ***2*** I need this data model:

```
[
 ['row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2'],
 ['row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2'],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested for loops, like this:

```
let number = 2;
let outputArray = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= number; i ++){
    let tempArray = [];
    for(let j = 1; j <= number; j ++){
        tempArray.push(`row ${i} col ${j}`);//Template literal
    }
    outputArray.push(tempArray);
}
```